# Function works when I don't login to WordPress but when I login then it doesn't work

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

In my function I just tried to add fees based on some calculation. It is working when I am not logged in to the site, but I don't really know what makes my function stop when I am logged on the site. When I login the page 'Cart' doesn't show anything. It is like a white page with the Title (Cart) and that is all. It doesn't show the products or anything else except the Title Cart. This is my code:

```
function prefix_add_discount_linett(  $cart, $cart_object, $cart_item, $cart_item_key, $wc  ) {    

      $category=wc_get_product_category_list( $cart_item['product_id'] );
            $h1 = preg_replace('/<a[^>]*?>([\\s\\S]*?)<\/a>/','\\1', $category);

           global $woocommerce, $termID;

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) 
            $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
     $termID = $_SESSION['clicked'];


    function cat_cart_count( $cat_name, $termID ) {
      $termID = $_SESSION['clicked'];
        $cat_count = 0;        

        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) 

            if( (has_term( $cat_name, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) && $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['value']=='sénior') || (has_term( $cat_name, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) && $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['value']=='méga')){
                $cat_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
     }else{
      continue;
     }


        if($termID=="take_away"){
            if ($cat_count%2 == 1) {     

              $cat_count=$cat_count/2;
              floor($cat_count);           

    }else{

      $cat_count=$cat_count/2;
       floor($cat_count);
    }
                }else{
     if ($cat_count%3 == 0) {        

              $cat_count=$cat_count/3;
              floor($cat_count);

    }else{

      $cat_count=$cat_count/3;
       floor($cat_count);

    }

                }
                return floor($cat_count);
    }
    cat_cart_count( 16 );

    function cat_cart_prix_min( $cat_name ) {

        $testprix = 900000;        

        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item)  
         if( (has_term( $cat_name, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) && $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['value']=='sénior') || (has_term( $cat_name, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) && $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['value']=='méga')){

              if ($testprix>$cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['price_original']) {
                $testprix = $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['price_original'];

              }else{
                continue;
              }
        }else{
      continue;
        }return $testprix;


    }

     if($termID=="delivery" || $termID=="take_away"){
        $prixmin = cat_cart_prix_min(16);

     $total_QN = cat_cart_count( $cat_name );

    $simo = $total_QN*$prixmin;

    }

      $discount = $simo;
      if($discount>0){
      $cart->add_fee( __( 'Offertes', 'yourtext-domain' ) , -$discount );
    }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_linett' );
```

Comment: Not sure but the culprit will probably be something with the `$_SESSION['clicked'];`